# How to make an Angular 5 + Node app with CAS authentication?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, cas

I'm currently trying to build an app that needs the user to authenticate with CAS (Centrale Authentication Service) to use it. I'm using Angular 5 for the front-end and Node.js for the back-end.

To authenticate the user on the server side I'm using a module called 'r-cas-authentication' which creates an express-session when the user is authenticated. The fact is I don't know how to check on the Angular side if the user is authenticated and otherwise redirect him on the CAS authentication page.

Do you know how I could do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deal with this on `angular` side. Just have the Node server redirect the unauthenticated users to a login page, always. Browser sets the session headers, and your Node server will see there's no auth and send a redirect. The `r-cas-authentication` module mentions the `bounce` and `bounce_redirect` options in the docs, this will further streamline the process.

Your node instance will serve the login page.:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => res.sendFile('path/to/login.html'));
```

Additionally, your assets (frontend scripts, css, images, etc) are (usually) free to have:

```
app.get('/assets', express.static(pathToStaticDirectory));
```

Also, you have authentication endpoint:

```
app.get( '/authenticate', cas.bounce_redirect );
```

Next, it needs to serve the Angular app. It will, however, require a *cas session* here. We target `'/home'` but it can be another path like '/' or whatever have you.

```
app.get('/home', cas.bounce, express.static(pathToAngularAppDirectory);
```

Finally, you will likely have REST API endpoints that you want protected:

```
app.use('/api', cas.block, appRoutes);
```

Now, here's what happens. Request comes infrom the browser. It hits the `'/home'` route. Since the browser is on it'S first visit, there's no authentication headers set. It will hit the `cas.bounce()` block and get redirected to `/login` route. Once it goes there, it gets served login.html*.

You enter your login data there and hit Login button - the page gets submitted, and `cas` middleware authenticates the user - sets the session data and all to browser. Browser will cary these around with it (note I say browser, not Angular). *It also redirects the user back to '/home' page.*

Now your browser *has* the session info, so it gets a pass on the route, gets served the Angular files, the app starts normally. All is cool.

There is one more case you might wanna handle from Angular.

Let's say your session expired. And the browser was left open or something. The user revisits the page - all cool, `cas.bounce` will redirect the user back to login form.

But what if the user simply clicks "refresh" in your app? Then Angular's `HttpClient` gets a 401 response (as per node module docs). You can have a simple [http interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+http+interceptor) that does a `window.location.reload()` or similar (basically a full page reload, not client-side navigation), and on a page reload, your app get's caught into `cas.bounce` because it's trying to reload /home unauthenticated.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I'm sorry I don't get it. If I call the server from the client side, it will need to redirect me to the CAS login page running on a different server and the http request from angular won't be correct. So the redirection need to come from the Angular side, and if I do that well the server authenticates the user but the session is lost when the user is redirected the page of origin.

Comment: It's nothing to do with angular per se, it is just browser mechanism. I will expand the answer to try to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer, I did exactly that and It worked perfectly !